# Formula(Text) Field Displayed in a Time Format Not Sorted Properly in List View

Tags: formula-field, sort

I have a formula(text) field created that fetches only the time part of a date/time field.

**Formula(Text)** field: **Time__c**

However, upon sorting list view by that formula field, it does not display the expected result.

For example:

`10:00 AM
 9:00 AM`

I've been clicking the ascend arrow but it always puts the record with 10:00 AM value first and always tops the 9:00 AM. Seems like it treats it as 1 and not as 10.

How could I sort this field properly?

Answer (score 1):

That filtering is correct. Text filtering is simply alphanumeric, and just as `A...` comes before `B...`, you similarly observe `1...` comes before `9...`.

The simplest approach is just to change the **`Formula Return Type`** to `Time` rather than `Text`. Then sorting should work as you expect.

[image: Formula Return Type Radio Select]

Comment: For initial testing, I've created a new formula field with Time return type, and tried with this value: `TIMEVALUE(Date_Time_Field__c)`. However, time was not displayed in HH:MM AM/PM format. It looks something like this: `2:01:00 AM`. Plus time is not in local format (user settings follows local time).